# sql statement with select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL statement which I could not get to work, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is the SQL :

```
INSERT INTO data
(id_user,id_inf)
VALUES
(
 (SELECT userid FROM t4_adsmanager_ads WHERE userid NOT IN (select id_user from data) ),
 (SELECT id     FROM t4_adsmanager_ads WHERE id     NOT IN (select id_inf from data))
)
```

as what I wanted to do is in `t4_adsmanager_ads` I have ads created by users

Let's say user in `t4_adsmanager_ads` with id = 47 have ads with id= 1,2,3

in data table I have

```
     id   id_inf   id_user
```

and i want it to be like that

```
         id   id_inf   id_user
         50     1        47
         51     2        47
         52     3        47
```

edit :
my errors is no error just did not work
thx

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? That you run the command and nothing happens? Does MySQL give you output that tells you how many rows were matched and how many were changed?

Comment: Are the data actually stored so that id_inf has a value of "1,2,3" where id_user is 47?

Comment: the data are already stored , so i want this sql to copy them to data table . dont work mean no data copied and nothing happen .

Comment: @gosto Yes I realize that t4_adsmanager_ads has data in it.  I am asking if there are records where id_inf has values like "1,2,3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current syntax requires that the subselects return exactly one record, which is not the case in your example.

I suggest you create a `UNIQUE` index in the `data` table over the composite columns `(id_user, id_inf)`:

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD UNIQUE INDEX (id_user, id_inf);
```

And then you merely need use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) with the `IGNORE` modifier:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO data (id_user, id_inf) SELECT userid, id FROM t4_adsmanager_ads;
```

Comment: waw :) , when i saw the result i smiled :) , it worked by this last sql u gave me , thx :) , but i didnt need to alter something or add something , just tried this last sql and it worked

Comment: @gosto: Without creating the `UNIQUE` index (assuming it doesn't already exist), you may end up with duplicate records in the `data` table.

Comment: maybe i dont understand you , but i have UNIQUE  index which is id ,and in this data table i have like that `id   id_inf   id_user` and id is unique

Comment: ay there is something wrong :( . if user add an ad , the query will add everytime the precedent values :( . forexemple one add an ad it will be like that (1,2,3) the second ad will insert like that (1,2,3,1,2,3,4) so it repeats every time the precedent ids

Comment: @gosto: Hence why you should create the `UNIQUE` index, as advised.

Comment: i dont know what i will create :( , i dont understand you.

Comment: with this `ALTER TABLE data` i will remove my table ? i will run this query of alter ?

Comment: @gosto: The `ALTER TABLE` command won't remove your table, it will only add the index to it.

Comment: thx :) , i have add this alter and it works now good without duplications :) , i wonder where you have learned this sql :) , can u give me where u have learned pls :)

Comment: @gosto: Entirely self-taught; mostly from reading the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/).